# Do I need to unit test web service request dispatcher (Java)?

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, testing

This class is simply a request dispatcher. It takes request and response objects, and pass down the work according the request type. Application logic is tested. Mocking has to be avoided. How can I write unit test for this dispatcher without turning the test into integration or system test? How are dispatchers usually tested?

---

EDIT: I was told to avoid mocking. I don't think I can change that decision.

Comment: Sounds impossible without mocking. Why avoid mocking if you don't want to turn it into integration testing? It already depends on two different objects (request and response).

Comment: Whoever told you to avoid mocking needs to be told that without mocking, the test will probably turn into an integration test. That person, who I presume dictates the rest of your objectives, needs to make a choice as to which of his objectives (no mocking, unit test instead of integration test) is more important.

Comment: This sounds almost more of a political problem -- like your boss doesn't quite understand the constraint under which you must work to test this class.

Comment: what do you mean by request dispatcher? Is it javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher?

Comment: @IvanYatskevich No, it's an internal request dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

There should be two parts to the code; the first is the marshalling of data between the web layer and dispatching, the second is dispatching to handlers.

Dispatching can be tested using "plain" unit testing, it's just logic to map arbitrary criteria to handlers.

The marshalling layer requires either mocking, or enough integration to create a web request and watch its routing, what's returned from its handler, etc. [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is one solution, there are a ton of others.

Answer (score 0):

Use mocks. Do the unit tests.

If you start picking and chosing which parts to test and what not to test, you might as well not test anything at all.

Then again, you might just name them "Bootstraps" or "Imposter" or some other name and get around the restrictions. Alternative, you might be able to hand-code the mocked objects and get around the restrictions that way.